# Flutter : Firebase notifications when app is closed

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been searching a lot regarding my problems, but couldn't find any solution.

I have a Flutter app connected to Firestore.

Basically, I want to trigger a notification when the value of a certain field in Firestore is updated. Here's my code :

```
class FirestoreService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

  void listenToFirestoreChanges() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(clients)
        .doc(uid)
        .collection(requests)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.modified &&
            change.doc.data() != null &&
            change.doc.data()!['status'] == 'done') {
          sendNotification(
            'This is the title',
            'This is the body',
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void sendNotification(String title, message) async {
    String? token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();

    if (token != null) {
    
      await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
              'key=MY_KEY'
        },
        body: json.encode(<String, dynamic>{
          'priority': 'high',
          'data': <String, dynamic>{
            'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'status': 'done',
            'body': message,
            'title': title,
          },
          'notification': <String, dynamic>{
            'title': title,
            'body': message,
            'android_channel_id': 'test'
          },
          'to': token,
        }),
      );

    }
  }
}
```

I call the function in `main.dart` :

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  FirestoreService().listenToFirestoreChanges();
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirestoreService().listenToFirestoreChanges();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(child: MyApp()));
}
```

And I call this function in the `initState` of `main.dart` :

```
  initNotificationData() {
    var androidInitialize =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launch');
    var iOSInitialize = const IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationsSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()),
      );
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      BigTextStyleInformation bigTextStyleInformation = BigTextStyleInformation(
        message.notification!.body.toString(),
        htmlFormatBigText: true,
      );
      AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
          AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'channelID', 'channelName', 'channelDescription',
              importance: Importance.high,
              styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation,
              priority: Priority.high,
              playSound: true);

      NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
          iOS: IOSNotificationDetails());
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, message.notification?.title,
          message.notification?.body, platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: message.data['title']);
    });
  }
```

So this code is working : when I update the field 'status' value to 'done', it triggers the notification even when I'm not in the app (but the app is still in background).

So here's the problems :

1. When I shut down the app completely or disconnect the device from VSCode, I don't receive the notifications any more. Only when I reconnect the device, I receive all the notifications at once.
2. When I click on the notification, it doesn't redirect me to NewScreen().

Are those 2 problems linked somehow ?

I've been struggling for hours, following tutorials, updated AndroidManifest.xml, and documentation but still couldn't find what I'm doing wrong. What am I missing here ?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but if I'm correct you are using the app to listen for changes in the Firestore database and then send a notification. That will  only work if the app is active. If you want notifications sent when the app is closed and the database changes, you need a server side function to do that. Such as a firebase cloud function.

Comment: So the app can't "listen" to firestore changes if it's not opened ?

Comment: If it's closed it's like you turned off your laptop/PC. It can do nothing. It doesn't exist anymore. Read up on using firebase cloud functions to do this .